# Show website pop up in Project Westminster - UWP apps

Tags: win-universal-app, azure-mobile-services

I am using [Project Westminster](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/06/project-westminster-in-a-nutshell/) for hosting a website as `UWP` app. The website uses `Azure mobile services` for authenticating users against Microsoft and Google account. When the website is running in the browser and user chooses to sign-in (lets say using Microsoft as authentication provider) a separate pop-up window opens showing the login.live.com page where user can input the required credentials.
But when the website is running as a `UWP` app, this login pop-up does not appear so the user is not able to log into their account.
Here is the `JavaScript` code used for performing login:

```
var MobileServiceClient = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient;
var client = new MobileServiceClient(<Azure Mobile Service URL>, <Azure Mobile Service Key>);
client.login("microsoftaccount").done(function(results) {
    //Do something
});
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Westminster, but our Windows client SDKs use the Web Authentication Broker to login: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Mt270196.aspx I believe you should be able to call into these apis from your app

If you can call that from your app you should be able to use that to perform the authentication and then pass the auth token to your Mobile Service using the client flow authentication. Some documentation on client flow auth here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/